# How to automate creation of api keys in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm looking at this part of the documentation where AWS offers a path through the UI to create API keys: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html#api-gateway-usage-plan-create-apikey

[image]

but is there a way to automate this in AWS? Optimally it would be some sort of http triggered function that returns a newly generated api key, on demand.

Comment: hey were you able to figure out the IAM permissions to do this?

Comment: the project where this is relevant is on hiatus for the time being so no unfortunately @foboi1122

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to automate this in AWS? Optimally it would be some sort of http triggered function that returns a newly generated api key, on demand.

There are **several ways** you could automate creation of API keys, depending on your requirements.

For example, you could use [create-api-key](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/apigateway/create-api-key.html) to create a key for a given API. This would be most useful to execute on an EC2 instance or a local workstation.

For an HTTP trigger, you could create new API in API Gateway with `AWS_PROXY` integration to a **lambda function**. The lambda could use [create_api_key](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_api_key) boto3 method to generate the key and return to the caller.

Yet another way would be to use **SSM Automation**'s action [aws:executeAwsApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-executeAwsApi.html) to trigger the `create-api-key` based on some criteria you specify. These criteria could be determined by some CloudWatch Events, for example.

Comment: i like your second suggestion, ill update with whether it worked!